# “Can I ask it?”

Tags: phrases, british-english

In the TV show Ted Lasso, one character (of Nigerian descent) asks another for a roll of tape by saying “Can I ask it?” I wasn’t familiar with this phrasing. I think an American would have said “Could I have that?” I was curious to know if this is a common phrase in British or Nigerian English.

Comment: It's far from idiomatic in the UK. 'Ask' is not mandatorily without a direct object; there are 'ask a question' and 'ask a favour [of]', of course, and the dated/formal 'Can we really ask this of him?' But _can/could_ together with _have_ or _pass_ or _hand [me]_ (and _please_) would be used in the UK.

Comment: If you were very timid and polite you might say "Can I ask for some tape?" But that's with "for".